# Add 2 float values in UILabel from 2 difference functions

Tags: swift, text, uilabel

I'm new to Swift and I'm stuck with this simple issue, hope someone can help.

I'm trying to assign float value to 2 `UILabels` deliveryCollectionLabel and adminFeeLabel with if logic in 2 different functions as shown below and then on third function named totalCost I'm trying to add them values but I'm getting an error:

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two '()' operands

first question: is below the correct way to assign a `Float` value to labels deliveryCollectionLabel and adminFeeLabel?

secondly: what is the correct way to add values of these 2 functions into `Float` which will be used to add to another float value later on in the code?

```
private func deliveryCharge() {
    if deliveryCollectionLabel.text! == "Delivery" {
        deliveryChargeLabel.text! = "2.50"
    } else {
        deliveryChargeLabel.text! = "0.00"
    }
}
private func adminFee () {
    adminFeeLabel.text! = "0.50"
}
private func totalCost() {
   var totalOrderCost = 0
    totalOrderCost = deliveryCharge() + adminFee()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it that way.

```
private func getDeliveryCharge() -> Double {
    if deliveryCollectionLabel.text! == "Delivery" {
         return 2.50
    }
  return 0.0
}

private func getAdminFee() -> Double {
    return 0.50
}

private func getTotalCost() -> Double {
  return getDeliveryCharge() + getAdminFee()
}
```

[USE]:

```
deliveryChargeLabel.text = "\(getDeliveryCharge())"
adminFeeLabel.text = "\(getAdminFee())"
print("\(getTotalCost())")
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks guys, this has worked for me. I'm now facing another issue I cannot seem to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Make both of your functions return a float value, e.g:

```
private func adminFee () - > Float{
    adminFeeLabel.text! = "0.50"
    return 0.5
}
```

Currently your functions assign strings to variables, but if you want to add them, they need to also return something, and this is what the error is complaining about.

Comment: Delivery and admin charges now working and update dynamically but the issue I'm facing now is the the total cost not changing dynamically. It includes both delivery and admin charges even when collection option is selected. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong with below codes.                                                            private func returnBasketTotalPrice()-> String {
        var totalPrice = 0.0
            for item in allItems {
                totalPrice += item.price
        }
        return convertToCurrency(totalPrice + getTotalCost())
}